# Ten obligations in 三字经

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature, poetry

Here's the final excerpt from part one of 三字经 [1]:

> 父子恩 夫婦從  兄則友  弟則恭  長幼序  友與朋 君則敬  臣則忠  此十義  人所同

Simplified Chinese:

> 父子恩  夫妇从  兄则友  弟则恭  长幼序  友与朋 君则敬  臣则忠  此十义  人所同

Translation [2]:

> Kindness between father and child,
>
> harmony between husband and wife,
>
> friendliness from elder brothers,
>
> respect from younger brothers.
>
> Precedence between elders and youngers,
>
> support between friends,
>
> Respect from the sovereigns,
>
> loyalty from the subjects.
>
> These ten obligations are the same for all.

I count only eight obligations in this excerpt. Where, then, are the remaining two that the autor of the poem speaks of?

[1] http://www.dfg.cn/gb/zhhy/whdc/04-sanzijin.htm

[2] https://www.yellowbridge.com/onlinelit/sanzijing.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the trimetrical classic (三字經) is extracted from ancient confucianism literatures, in three characters verses.

the eight verses in question are derived from [禮記　禮運](https://ctext.org/liji/li-yun/zh?searchu=%E4%BA%BA%E7%BE%A9)

> 父慈．子孝．兄良．弟弟．夫義．婦聽．長惠．幼順．君仁．臣忠**十**者．謂之人義

if you've some knowledge of confucianism, you can find components of [五倫](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000159520) from these eight verses:

> 君臣．父子．兄弟．夫妻．朋友

each one of these have two "人義"; so five of them makes ten "人義".

have fun :)